rearranging with same timestamp using awk
I have a couple of files.
cat << EOF > file1.txt
 20190130150000 #timestamp-1
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999      6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999      9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130151000 #timestamp-2
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130152000 #timestamp-3
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999

EOF
cat << EOF > file2.txt
 20190130150000 #timestamp-1
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130151000 #timestamp-2
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130152000 #timestamp-3
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999

EOF
I am looking for a awk script to rearrange it in the the following way:
Write all the same timestamps together with its subsequent rows:
Please note: There is no such #timestamp words in the files, I just mentioned it to make understandble.
So the desire output will be like:
cat << EOF > out.txt
 20190130150000
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130150000
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130151000
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999      6.99      0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130151000
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130152000
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130152000
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999      5.99      0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999

EOF
My script:
awk '
{
    if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]{14}$/) {
        timestamp = $1
        print timestamp
        next
    }
    print
}' file1.txt file2.txt

This script is just printing the same inputs. It is not printing desire output.

You describe a problem. You post a script to solve the problem. What is your question?

@user1934428 thanks for looking at my problem. It is not printing the desire output. It is just printing the input files.

just printing the same inputs : Of course it does. Your awk clause is executed for each line (there is no guard in front), and it contains an unconditional print statement. That means it prints each line to stdout. What else did you expect from it, and why?

@user1934428 yes.. you are right.

Using the Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom with any awk+sort+cut for any number of input files of practically any size and containing any order and/or values of timestamps (so it'll work for 1 input file or 100000 input files where some have timestamp 1 before timestamp 2, some have timestamps that don't exist in any other file, massive input files, etc.)
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v OFS='\t' '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{14}$/{t=$1} {print t, NR, $0}' "${@:--}" |
sort -k1,1n -k2,2n |
cut -f3-


$ ./tst.sh file{1,2}.txt
 20190130150000 #timestamp-1
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999      6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999      9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130150000 #timestamp-1
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130151000 #timestamp-2
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130151000 #timestamp-2
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130152000 #timestamp-3
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130152000 #timestamp-3
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999

That's doing the following:

Decorate - awk -v OFS='\t' '...' adds the most recent timestamp read from the input followed by the current line number in front of each input line so we can in step 2 sort on those to get the desired output order.
Sort - sort -k1,1n -k2,2n sorts by the timestamp and then by line number added in step 1 to group all lines by timestamp while retaining their original relative input order.
Undecorate - cut -f3- removes the leading timestamp and line number added by awk in step 1 to get back to just the original content of each input line.

As well as the conciseness and flexibility of the above approach, one additional benefit over trying to do it all in awk or some other tool is that we're only storing 1 line at a time in memory using awk so it'll work even for massive input files since only sort has to handle all of the input "in memory" but it's designed to be able to do that by using demand paging, etc. while awk is not and in fact awk would slow down by orders of magnitude as it's array sizes increase if trying to store huge amounts of input.
If you're still not sure what the above is doing, just run the awk script on it's own to see what it does (adds 2 fields to the front of the input):
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{14}$/{t=$1} {print t, NR, $0}' file{1,2}.txt
20190130150000  1        20190130150000 #timestamp-1
20190130150000  2            56   39
20190130150000  3         P                                         A
20190130150000  4         S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
20190130150000  5        -9999 -9999      6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130150000  6        -9999 -9999      9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130151000  7        20190130151000 #timestamp-2
20190130151000  8            56   39
20190130151000  9         P                                         A
20190130151000  10        S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
20190130151000  11       -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130151000  12       -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130152000  13       20190130152000 #timestamp-3
20190130152000  14           56   39
20190130152000  15        P                                         A
20190130152000  16        S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
20190130152000  17       -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130152000  18       -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130150000  19       20190130150000 #timestamp-1
20190130150000  20          33   55.3
20190130150000  21        R                                         A
20190130150000  22        S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
20190130150000  23       -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130150000  24       -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130151000  25       20190130151000 #timestamp-2
20190130151000  26          33   55.3
20190130151000  27        R                                         A
20190130151000  28        S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
20190130151000  29       -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130151000  30       -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130152000  31       20190130152000 #timestamp-3
20190130152000  32          33   55.3
20190130152000  33        R                                         A
20190130152000  34        S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
20190130152000  35       -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130152000  36       -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999

Then pipe that output to sort to see what changes (lines reordered according to the numeric value of those 2 added fields):
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{14}$/{t=$1} {print t, NR, $0}' file{1,2}.txt |
    sort -k1,1n -k2,2n
20190130150000  1        20190130150000 #timestamp-1
20190130150000  2            56   39
20190130150000  3         P                                         A
20190130150000  4         S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
20190130150000  5        -9999 -9999      6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130150000  6        -9999 -9999      9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130150000  19       20190130150000 #timestamp-1
20190130150000  20          33   55.3
20190130150000  21        R                                         A
20190130150000  22        S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
20190130150000  23       -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130150000  24       -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130151000  7        20190130151000 #timestamp-2
20190130151000  8            56   39
20190130151000  9         P                                         A
20190130151000  10        S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
20190130151000  11       -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130151000  12       -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130151000  25       20190130151000 #timestamp-2
20190130151000  26          33   55.3
20190130151000  27        R                                         A
20190130151000  28        S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
20190130151000  29       -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130151000  30       -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130152000  13       20190130152000 #timestamp-3
20190130152000  14           56   39
20190130152000  15        P                                         A
20190130152000  16        S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
20190130152000  17       -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130152000  18       -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130152000  31       20190130152000 #timestamp-3
20190130152000  32          33   55.3
20190130152000  33        R                                         A
20190130152000  34        S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
20190130152000  35       -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
20190130152000  36       -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999

Then pipe to cut to see what changes (first 2 fields removed):
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{14}$/{t=$1} {print t, NR, $0}' file{1,2}.txt |
    sort -k1,1n -k2,2n |
    cut -f3-
 20190130150000 #timestamp-1
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999      6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999      9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130150000 #timestamp-1
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130151000 #timestamp-2
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130151000 #timestamp-2
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130152000 #timestamp-3
     56   39
  P                                         A
  S-4 B                               4.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     6.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     9.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 20190130152000 #timestamp-3
    33   55.3
  R                                         A
  S-4 B                                3.     E     F      3
 -9999 -9999     5.99       0.000 -9999 -9999
 -9999 -9999     7.99       0.000 -9999 -9999


Really a very nice method, for general use. This script also works for more than 2 files. I appreciate it. Thanks

You can store the timestamp-to-content mapping in the first file in an array, and output the corresponding content from the cache for each timestamp in the second file before outputting the second file's content:
NR == FNR {
    if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]{14}$/) {
        if (timestamp)
            store[timestamp] = content
        timestamp = $1
        content = $0
    } else
        content = content RS $0
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    store[timestamp] = content
}
$1 ~ /^[0-9]{14}$/ {
    print store[$1]
}
1

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/EcstaticDirtyParallelprocessing

Thanks. It is printing the content of file2.txt. It is not printing the content of file1.txt.

Have you tried the code in my demo environment? It works there (by running awk -f program.awk file1.txt file2.txt). Also, make sure all timestamps in both files having no leading spaces. The file snippets in your question have an indentation of an extra space after the first timestamp.

Your demo environment is not opening. Idk why? Yes, I tried with awk -f program.awk file1.txt file2.txt . I have leading spaces before the timestamps. Even deleting the space is not printing two files.

The first timestamp in each file snippet in your question has no leading space, while the rest do. This inconsistency causes the /^[0-9]{14}$/ pattern not to match $0. I've updated the answer so that it's more lenient by testing $1 instead of $0, like you do in your attempt.

Thanks. It is now printing correctly. But still the output deleting the leading space. I think I can do it by myself.

I see. I've updated my answer so it preserves the leading space then.

you can try simple way below:
cat <yourfiles> | awk '/[0-9]{14}/ { print $1;}'
There appears to be one whitespace char in front of timestamp.

That's not what the OP is trying to do and, if it were, it's not how to do it as it has a UUOC.
